# How to send data from View to Controller when filtering for multiple factors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

In my application I have a selection list where I filter products by category, and there is also an option to filter by product name. 
The issue is that searching is done through a text box and filtering for category is through the selection list and these 2 send separate requests to the server. 
Both these functionalities work perfectly when used separately but when I want to filter for category, and then by product name, filtering for category is reset, ignoring what I have selected.

I am sending an Ajax call in both filtering cases. I have tried using Session variables or Cache instead of sending data with Ajax but I could not get it to work, maybe that could solve the problem.

This is the controller that I am sending the data to.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Foods(string foodName, string _category)
    {
        var foodViewModel = new FoodListViewModel()
        {
            Foods = MenuItemLogic.GetFoodsToDisplay(foodName, _category),
            Categories = MenuItemLogic.GetCategories()
        };

        return PartialView("Foods",foodViewModel);
    }
```

This is how I did filtering by category.

```
<ul id="food-filter-list" class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Összes", "Foods", "MenuItem" , null , new 
                AjaxOptions()
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "page-content",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    AllowCache = true
                } , new { @class = Request["_category"] == "" || Request["_category"] == null ? "chosen-filter food-filter-item" : "food-filter-item" })
            </li>
            @foreach (var category in Model.Categories.Keys)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink(category, "Foods", "MenuItem", new{_category = category}, new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        UpdateTargetId = "page-content",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        AllowCache = true
                    },  new { @class = Request["_category"] == category ? "chosen-filter food-filter-item" : "food-filter-item" })
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
```

This is how I did filtering by product name.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Foods", "MenuItem", 
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "page-content",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        }))
    {
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 10px">
        <div class="row">
            <input style="width: 87%; border-radius:0.3em" type="text" name="foodName" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Keresés" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

I would like to send these 2 together in 1 request if possible or store the selected category in some way, so that when I input text to filter by product name too, the chosen category is not reset and searching does not only apply by product name.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you didn't pass the value of the `category` to the `product` and vice versa. Have you tried to set the selected values from the controller in the ViewBag then send them again through the form?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand what you meant by setting the selected values from the controller, but yes the issue is that I did not know how to "store the value of the 2 filtering values" on the view side such that for example when I filter for  category and product name at the same time I first select the category, save the value in a "variable" and send that "variable" with the form submission as well.